# Using pattern matching in Low Seg2Cat

Tags: low-seg2cat, regular-expressions

I need to get the IDs of particular segments in the URL, shown in bold (i.e. segments 2, 3 and 4):

> /grid/**strategic/corporate/uk**/jim/tweets

They could also look like this (i.e. no category has been set):

> /grid/**-/-/-**/jim/tweets

I'm assuming I would need a regex pattern match to do this and then use the {segment_category_ids} tag to pull them out in a list such as 37&342.

Not entirely sure how I should go about writing that for the settings though. I tried this:

```
^/[a-z-_0-9]*/[a-z-_0-9]*/[a-z-_0-9]*/[a-z-_0-9]*
```

Which works OK in a regexp checker but the I find that the tag {segment_category_ids} doesn't get rendered in the template.

How should I be providing this in the settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex option in Low Seg2Cat's settings is meant for something else: when set Low Seg2Cat will *only* set the `{segment_n_category_x}` variables *when the URI matches the given pattern*.

I take it you *want* to have access to those vars in all cases, so you should leave it blank.

If you do want to use the regex option, make sure you also add [the delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) to the pattern. In your case, that would mean the pattern could look something like this:

```
#^(/[\w-]+){4}$#
```

Comment: Thanks, Low. All I want to do is limit the number of segments that are set. There's an option to set ALL segments, and I assumed the reg would enable us to only set those that match the expression. Is the best way forward just to use conditionals as @andrew-fairlie suggested?

Comment: Depends on what you want to use. If you're using the regex, the extension will trigger (setting the vars) if there are exactly 4 segments. If you just want to use `{segment_category_ids}`, then leave the regex blank. It will return an empty string for an URI like `/grid/-/-/-/jim/tweets` and it will return something like `1&2&3` for an URI like `grid/strategic/corporate/uk/jim/tweets`, given that *strategic*, *corporate* and *uk* are valid category_url_titles and the other segments aren't.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now. My concern would be that somebody could create a category called tweets and then we'd end up with the ID returned, when it's only IDs from segments 2, 3 and 4 which are category-related

Comment: Then I'd still leave the regex field empty and use {segment_2_category_id}&{segment_3_category_id}&{segment_4_category_id} instead.

Answer (score 0):

With LowSeg2 Cat could you do...

```
{if segment_2!="-"}{segment_2_category_id}&{/if}
{if segment_3!="-"}{segment_3_category_id}&{/if}
{if segment_4!="-"}{segment_4_category_id}{/if} {!-- No & here because it's the last segment --}
```

That should do the job.

Comment: I could, yes. But I wanted to understand the reg ex approach as it seems like a cleaner solution